# Hotmail account is automatically sending emails, no evidence in Sent folder 

Tags: spam-prevention, outlook.com

After clicking a link in a message, my Hotmail account sent emails to all the people in my address book.

The email itself is not present in the Sent folder items. Bizarrely, the problem occurs from my Android smartphone because I haven't used my PC in last two days.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I've already changed my password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform a virus scan on your computer.  The chances of a hacker sending random emails on your account is very slim.  More than likely, the link you clicked performed a drive-by download and loaded malware on your computer.  If the malware sent the same link you clicked to all your contacts, you should tell them to immediately scan their computer for viruses if they clicked it.

Comment: the ip is from venezuela. my account has been hacked

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your account may have been hacked and the 'hacker' in question has removed all trace of the sent e-mail from your online account.

From what you have described, I believe that your phone automatically stores copies of all sent/received e-mails locally (like most other smartphones do), regardless of whether or not they have been deleted from your online account.  Therefore, if your phone had downloaded a copy of the sent e-mail before said 'hacker' had removed all trace of the e-mail, that would explain why it appears to have been sent from your phone rather than from your online account.  Think of it as a misconception, if you like.

My advice would be to change your password once again as it sounds very suspicious indeed.  Make sure that you **never** give your password to anybody, regardless of who they are.

You should also observe your account (activity) for the next week to see if anything suspicious has happened, and if not, then that should hopefully have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with Gmail, where I would send a mail and the same mail would be repeatedly sent to the same recipients several times, over the course of the day.

It was a bug/issue with Google Mail, there were a lot of complaints. It was fixed after a day or so.

I wonder if that is the case here with Hotmail.

Comment: the email in my case is explicitly spam

Answer (score 0):

Check whether mail is actually coming from you by looking at message source (click the dropdown next to reply when you haev the message selected). It could be your e-mail address is simply being spoofed, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_spoofing